# Форма epay оплаты

Tags: php, html, xml, rsa, платежи

Добрый день!
Уже 3 дня бьюсь с проблемой, оплаты, собрал XML подписал его, но при отправки формы на тестовый/боевой сервер оплаты выдает ошибку:

**Authorization Error
We're sorry, the Server application is unavailable.
Possible reasons:
- Session time out
- System process error 
Recommendation:

- Please, change your firewall permission**

Подскажите как можно понять с чем это связано, прокси нет. Дайте совет как можно докопаться до ошибки? Перечитал много раз https://testpay.kkb.kz/doc/htm/xml_description.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю будет полезно для оплаты Банком Qazkom: `$data = '<merchant cert_id="в мануале" name="Demo Shop 3"><order order_id="'.$out["bookingcode"].'" amount="'.$out["price"].'" currency="398"><department merchant_id="123456789" amount="'.$out["price"].'"/></order></merchant>';$kkb = new KKBSign();
$kkb->invert();
$kkb->load_private_key("PAYSYS/cert.prv", "1q2w3e4r");$merchant_sign = '<merchant_sign type="RSA">'.$kkb->sign64($data).'</merchant_sign>';
$xml = "<document>".$data.$merchant_sign."</document>";
$xml = base64_encode($xml);
return $xml;`
Сам `require_once("kkbsign.class.php");` находится в мануале, проблема была в `$prvkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($c, $password) or die(openssl_error_string());` был заменен оригинал на `openssl_pkey_get_private`